# Inline verbatim text in ConTeXt

Tags: context, verbatim

I am trying to typeset some TeX code inline with ConTeXt. In LaTeX, there's `\verb` to handle that, but I do not find the equivalent in ConTeXt.

In the Wiki, there is some [suggestion](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text#In-line_text) code:

```
\def\typeTEX
  {\bgroup
   \def\processinlineverbatim##1%
     {\processingverbatimtrue
      \localcatcodestrue
      \def\endofverbatimcommand{\TEXendofcommand##1}%
      \bgroup
      \aftergroup\endofverbatimcommand
      \futurelet\next\doprocessinlineverbatim}%
   \initializetyping{TEX}%
   \startverbatimcolor
   \processinlineverbatim\egroup }
```

However, when I try to use that, I get this error:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 34 in file /.../xyz.tex: ! Undefined control sequence


\typeTEX ...cessinlineverbatim }\initializetyping 
                                                  {TEX}\startverbatimcolor \...
```

I have no idea what `\initializetyping` does and whether it is needed. If I remove it, I get the same message for `\startverbatimcolor` and so on. This macro does not seem usable. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Sounds like `\type{...}` is what you're looking for, [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/type) on the wiki. For TeX code specifically you can do, if you like, `\type[option=tex]{...}`. (The colour scheme of that is customizable, but the only way I know of changing it is a bit messy.)

Comment: Your wiki link does not work. How would I write a `}` in with `\type`?

Comment: Link should be fixed now. If the braces are balanced then you can just do `\type{...{...}...}`. Another option is using angle brackets as delimiters: `\type<<}>>`. Finally, you can also use the `\verb` style, and use any character you like to delimit: `\type|}|`.

Comment: Do you want to post that as answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll type it up now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For typing code inline you can use `\type`, which is described [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/type) on the wiki. It can be used as:

- `\type[optional arg]{content with balanced braces}`
- `\type[optional arg]<<content not containing the string ">>" anywhere>>`
- `\type[optional arg]|content not containing the string "|" anywhere|`

(In the third case here, you can use pretty much any single character as a delimiter, not just `|`, in the same way as LaTeX's `\verb` allows.) The optional argument `[...]`, if given, should be a list of key-value pairs: the valid options are exactly those that `\setuptype` understands ([here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuptype) on the wiki). According to the installation on my machine,

```
ConTeXt  ver: 2017.06.30 19:45 MKIV beta  fmt: 2017.7.5
```

the options that you can pass to `\type` are:

```
color   = COLOR
command = CSNAME
compact = absolute last (all)
escape  = yes (no) TEXT PROCESSOR->TEXT
left    = COMMAND
lines   = yes (no) normal hyphenated
option  = mp lua xml parsed-xml nested tex context none NAME
right   = COMMAND
space   = on (off) normal fixed stretch
tab     = (yes) no NUMBER
```

where I mimic the wiki's style, and use brackets `(...)` to indicate the default value.

If you find yourself passing the same options to `\type` again and again, then you might find `\definetype` useful, which is [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definetype) on the wiki. It works in the same way as all the `\define...` style commands in ConTeXt.

To mimic Taco's `\typeTEX` macro (which only works with MKII), you can define a new `type` as in the following

```
\definetype
  [typeTEX]
  [option=tex]

\starttext

\typeTEX!\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}!

\stoptext
```

This will apply TeX syntax hightlighting to the contents of `\typeTEX`.